# Windows Remote Control?

Tags: windows, windows-8, remote-access

I am trying to control Windows 8 from a remote client. As soon as I login though, the session on the remote computer is logged off to give it to my remote session.

What I am trying to do is to control the remote computer / desktop so that the person that sits in front of the computer can see what I am doing (mouse movements, windows, typing, etc.).

Within Linux I could easily achieve this by using x11vnc. Is that possible with the already installed Windows 8 tools? If not, is there any Open Source software that does that? Maybe even using VNC as protocol?

Comment: For vbuilt-in, see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-using-remote-desktop-connection#connect-using-remote-desktop-connection=windows-7  but, I prefer my answer (and it is more like you are used to, plus you can use it to replace x11vnc on Linux)

Comment: Also, see Wikipedia's Comparison of remote desktop software at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are any number of free VNC clients for Windows. For years now, I have relied exclusively on [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/).

> What I am trying to do is to control the remote computer / desktop so
>   that the person that sits in front of the computer can see what I am
>   doing (mouse movements, windows, typing, etc.).

Yup, TightVNC will do that - a ghost at the controls, as far as the bewildered user is concerned.

Plus you can use it to replace x11vnc on Linux

> TightVNC is a free remote control software package. With TightVNC, you
>   can see the desktop of a remote machine and control it with your local
>   mouse and keyboard, just like you would do it sitting in the front of
>   that computer. TightVNC is:
>
> ```
> free for both personal and commercial usage, with full source code available,
> useful in administration, tech support, education, and for many other purposes,
> cross-platform, available for Windows and Unix, with Java client included,
> compatible with standard VNC software, conforming to RFB protocol specifications.
> ```
>
> With TightVNC, you can:
>
> ```
> cut your expenses and save your time on traveling,
> help your friends and family to solve problems with their computers remotely,
> make sure nothing wrong is happening on your computers when you are away.
> ```

Comment: Very clear and full answer! Thanks a lot! No questions remaining.

Answer (score 0):

While TightVNC is lightweight and cross platform, so that you might start using it in place of x11vnc on your Linux boxen, the most popular & feature filled of such applications for Windows is [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/).

Unfortunately, my company's firewall won't let me access it, so [here's a typical review](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/remote-access/fl/teamviewer-review.htm).

As I said, it's the most popular & feature filled of such applications for Windows, but it is NOT free for commercial uses, which might have an impact.

Nor are the likes of [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/), etc.

For FOSS, you need to go to the xxxVNC series, of which I personally prefer TightVNC, but you can look at [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/), etc

Comment: Why Posting TWO answers ??

Comment: To offer an option.   If I put them into one big one it gets unwieldy.   More importantly, if the OP should accept that and not comment then future searchers will never know which one he chose. This way, if he chooses one of them by simply clicking the tick and not commenting, future searchers will be clear on what the accepted answer was.  Hmmm, do you think that we should have a meta discussion on what’s the best approach? Otoh, the system allows it, so it probably isn't seen as A Bad Thing.