# VNC-like application to remote control a Windows 10 PC (and blank screen)?

Tags: remote-access, windows-10

I'm looking for a **free, VNC-like application** that will allow me to **remote control a kiosk PC**, and most importantly, allow me to **blank the screen of the remote PC when required** (e.g. making config changes, applying updates, etc.) The remote kiosk PC is running **Windows 10** in a **commercial environment**.

I've been using UltraVNC but, following changes to Windows 8 (and newer), I can no longer use it to stop users seeing the screen of the remote kiosk PC. Consequently, kiosk users are able to still use the touch screen and interfere with the changes that I'm making onscreen.

EDIT: I don't want to log the current user out because I don't always want to prevent access to the kiosk software.

Any suggestions/recommendations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Remote Control?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/windows-remote-control)

Comment: What do you mean by blanking? Could you please post a screenshot?

Comment: By blanking, I mean 'display nothing' onscreen

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the Remote Desktop app that is built into Windows 10?  While you are connected, it logs out the local console and they see nothing until you release control.

Comment: If you are not happy with TeamViewer let me know and I will publish my alternative, however I do not disagree with James.

Comment: @michael-nancarrow I'd be happy to hear any alternatives. It is a commercial environment and budget is limited.

Comment: @UmberFerrule I have added my answer

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely suggest **[Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) version 10** (Version 11 auto logs out user on ending remote session). Team Viewer is free for non.commercial use and is quite easy to use. More details here: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/features/

- Link to download (version 10): https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/previous-versions/
- Link to download (latest version): http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/

It can blank screen and also disable input on the kiosk's side: [Super User question: *Block keyboard and mouse input of remote user in Teamviewer session*](https://superuser.com/questions/208188/block-keyboard-and-mouse-input-of-remote-user-in-teamviewer-session)

Answer (score 4):

[Remote Utilities](https://www.remoteutilities.com/product/)

Remote Utilities is a free solution to allow you remote to computers (*up to 10 machines*) for support. Some of the main features are:

1. Ability to save and export connections
2. Ability to remote install agent on PC's silently using NT Permissions
3. Ability to run Command Line, Task Manager, Full Control, Blank Screen and Disable Keyboard and Mouse Remotely
4. Ability to password protect host to prevent misuse of software
5. Ability to remote via DNS Name, IP or Internet ID

You can view the [feature page here.](https://www.remoteutilities.com/product/features/remote-access.php)

This program will perform all your requirements, with no user input required  at all.

It also supports functions such as recording screens, traversing the registry and chatting with the client direct.

If you like, I can add screenshots but believe my explanation satisfactory.